# "pickBy" the value in the value array of an object

Tags: javascript, lodash

I have an object that looks like:

```
let documents = {"A": [{"document":"test1", "serial":"123"}, {"document":"test2", "serial":"456N"}], "B": [{"document":"test3", "serial":"789N"}, {"document":"test24, "serial":"012"}]};
```

I was trying to get a filtered object that has serial number ending with "N":

```
{"A": [{"document":"test2", "serial":"456N"}, "B": [{"document":"test3", "serial":"789N"}]}
```

I was doing:

```
 let result = _.pickBy(documents, (docObjs, client) => {
       return _.filter(docObjs, ({serial}) => {
         return _.endsWith(serial, 'N');
       });
 });
```

But what I got was the original object (same as `documents`). Is there anything wrong?

Comment: Why is `documents` pluralized when you only have one of them (an object)? Why is `client_name` singular when the value it references is more than one (an array)?

Comment: @user633183 I updated the description so that it does not confuse you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Lodash**

Iterate the client's object with [`_.transform()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.5#transform). For each client, [filter](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.5#filter) the list of documents using [`_.endsWith()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.5#endsWith). If the list of documents is not [empty](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.5#isEmpty) (length 0), assign the client with filtered docs list to the result object:

```js
// added client C that will be filtered out
const documents = {"A": [{"document":"test1", "serial":"123"}, {"document":"test2", "serial":"456N"}], "B": [{"document":"test3", "serial":"789N"}, {"document":"test24", "serial":"012"}], "C": [{"document":"test25", "serial":"013"}]};

const result = _.transform(documents, (r, v, k) => {
  const docs = _.filter(v, ({ serial }) => _.endsWith(serial, 'N'));
  if(!_.isEmpty(docs)) r[k] = docs;
});

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.5/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

**Vanilla JS**

Get an array of client/document pairs with [`Object.entries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries). Using [`Array.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [`Array.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) remove all documents with serials that don't [`String.endsWith()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/endsWith) the letter N. Use `Array.filter()` to remove all entries with 0 documents. Convert back to an object using [`Array.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce):

```js
// added client C that will be filtered out
const documents = {"A": [{"document":"test1", "serial":"123"}, {"document":"test2", "serial":"456N"}], "B": [{"document":"test3", "serial":"789N"}, {"document":"test24", "serial":"012"}], "C": [{"document":"test25", "serial":"013"}]};

const result = Object.entries(documents)
  // filter the least of documents in each client entry
  .map(([k, v]) => [k, v.filter(({ serial }) => serial.endsWith('N'))])
  // filter clients that have 0 documents
  .filter(([k, v]) => v.length)
  // convert back to an object
  .reduce((r, [k, v]) => (r[k] = v, r), {});

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.5/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just using JS `ES6`, You can use `reduce` to loop thru the object keys. `filter` the array and use `endsWith` to check if the string ends with N

```js
let documents = {"A": [{"document":"test1", "serial":"123"}, {"document":"test2", "serial":"456N"}], "B": [{"document":"test3", "serial":"789N"}, {"document":"test24", "serial":"012"}]};

let result = Object.keys(documents).reduce((c, v) => {
  c[v] = documents[v].filter(o => o.serial.endsWith("N"));
  return c;
}, {});

console.log(result);
```

Doc: [filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter), [endsWith()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/endsWith)

Comment: 1) you're performing a shallow clone 2) if you're using lodash, why not use lodash's `clone`? 3) You don't need to clone

Comment: Thank you. Can I know what if I have multiple keys in `documents`? I think that explains the question of @user633183: I saved some time writing them but the actual object have multiple keys and values.

Comment: @user633183. Yeah, you are right, I dont need to clone it but on OP wants the output to be like `{client_name : [....]}`

Comment: @jsh6303 What do you mean by multiple keys? :)

Comment: @Eddie sorry for confusing everyone, the actual object is something like: `{"Eddie":[...], "Joe":[...]}`. How can we do similar work without knowing the name of the keys?

Comment: Are you trying to filter both Eddie and Joe?

Comment: @Eddie yes, should filter all keys of the object.